# JavaScript - What's the use of giving the choice of returning [Symbol.iterator]() in a [Symbol.iterator]()?

Tags: javascript

I built my code based on insights from this code:

https://github.com/davidflanagan/jstdg7/blob/master/ch12/Range.js

```
class SayHi {
  constructor (hi, repeat) {
    this.hi = hi;
    this.repeat = repeat;
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let next = 1;
    let last = this.repeat;
    let hi = this.hi;
    return {
      next() {
        if (next<=last) {
          let now = next;
          next++;
          return { value: hi+now };
        }
        else {
          return { done: true };
        }
      },
      // What's the use of this??
      [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this;
      }
    };
  }
}
let sayHi = new SayHi("HI", 3);
for(let x of sayHi) console.log(x);
```

I do not understand how this line of code works from the context of the whole program, because the program works without this code:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }
```

How does it work?  Why are we returning 2 functions for the outer Symbol.iterator?  How do we invoke each of the functions?

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next#return_value Also note the comment in the github link you shared "As a convenience, we make the iterator itself iterable."

Comment: @haakym, I understand how the next() code works, but I do not understand the comment "we make the iterator itself iterable"...

Comment: I've tried to understand iterables from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterables, but the example seems to require an understanding of generators, and of the `@@iterator` method... I'm not sure about these... there's no generator in my code...

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively simple concept, something that I have recently learned myself. If you have a normal iterator object that rsturns an object without the `[Symbol.iterator]` then this would throw an error:

```js
let data = [...iterator];
```

With this line, not only does the program not throw an error, but these two methods generate the exact same thing:

```js
let data1 = [...sayHiInstance];
let data2 = [...sayHiInstance[Symbol.iterator]()];
```

Comment: Thanks, when I removed `[Symbol.iterator]() {return this;}`, and then run the code `let data1 = [...sayHi]; console.log(data1);`, it runs without problems.  A TypeError is thrown only when I tried running `let data2 = [...sayHi[Symbol.iterator]()];`.  When will we need such a kind of code?

Comment: It is just a failsafe to prevent bugs or errors. Lol you probably would have gotten to it in a chapter or so, that is actually the book I am reading now and where i saw that failsafe.